# Envelope Events not being sent through Live integration

Tags: php, docusignapi

**Edit: Possible Explanation**

It seems as though the DocuSign connect system is getting "stuck" on that first notification that cannot be reached, and periodically attempts to send that same first notification over and over again. Upon testing in our own live environment, where the webhook *is* reachable, the event notifications reached our webhook and all the expected notifications were sent.

I have not confirmed this with anyone from DocuSign, but this appears to be what is happening. Will update this post again if more info is discovered.

**Original Question:**

We have built an ISV integration that sends envelopes on behalf of a user and notifies our system via webhook when the status of an envelope or envelope recipient changes. We have this working exactly as expected in the demo/sandbox environment, but after promoting our Integration Key to a live account we aren't receiving hits to the webhook. None of the events that connected to our webhook in the demo environment are happening in the live environment. We are using the exact same chunk of code to create these events and send the envelopes. We checked - our demo integration webhook still works perfectly since we promoted our Key, this is only an issue in the live environment.

Checking the Connect Logs in the DocuSign UI (`Settings > Connect > Logs`) and checking the API (`accounts/[ACCOUNT_ID]/connect/logs`) we don't see the successful or even failed logs we would expect. We receive the first event notification upon envelope creation, but nothing past that. We seem to get the same notification, the initial one that the envelope was sent, over and over, like on a schedule. It appears that the event notifications for recipient status and envelope status aren't being sent at all.

The envelopes are being sent in the live environment, and can be signed and completed, and the status of these signers and envelopes update correctly in the API and the DocuSign UI. But we're just not getting any notification to the webhook when these events are taking place.

**A note about our webhook URL:**

The system we have set up in our development environment has the event notifications being sent to a webhook URL that it will not be able to resolve because our dev environments are not publicly accessible. All of the Connect Logs that are attempted to be sent to our dev environment look like this:

```
Error: Exception in EnvelopeIntegration.RunIntegration: :: << REDACTED >> :: Error - The remote name could not be resolved: '<< REDACTED >>'
```

I am fully aware that our development webhooks are not being reached, but in our testing of the DocuSign demo/sandbox integration we simply looked at the Connection Logs of the demo account and could confirm that the events were sent correctly that way.

Comment: I'd recommend capturing an API log of a test send. If you post the EventNotification parameter (with your URL removed) it might help investigation.

Comment: @Drew Edited question with a dump of EventNotification

Comment: Does your URL begin with HTTPS? DocuSign has not allowed publishing to HTTP endpoints for some time.

Comment: Yes, all our URLs begin with https. I just ran a test to see if adding the `www` in front would change the result, but it appears to still be the same - demo will perform the correct event notification events but live will not. However, i'm wondering if the live implementation will stop sending event notifications if a remote name could not be resolved? I'll add more detail to the end of my question.